# Nodejs Sequelize is not inserting

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

OKay i have litteraly been staring at this for 2 hours now and i simply cannot find the mistake:

I have the following database table:

[image]

If you cannot tell it has 4 columns:

- id
- name
- organization_id
- competence_type_id

Using sequelize i am using the following code:

```
var Competence = sequelize.define('competence', {
            id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            organization_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            competence_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER

        }, {
            freezeTableName: true,
            instanceMethods: {
                retrieveAll: function (org_id,onSuccess, onError) {
                    Location.findAll({where: {organization_id: org_id}}, {})
                        .ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
                },
                retrieveById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                    Location.find({where: {id: quote_id}}, {raw: true})
                        .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
                },
                add: function (onSuccess, onError) {
                    var competence = this.dataValues;
                    Competence.build(competence)
                        .save().ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
                },
                updateById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                    var id = quote_id;
                    var quotes = this.quotes;

                    Location.update({quotes: quotes}, {where: {id: id}})
                        .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
                },
                removeById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                    Location.destroy({where: {id: quote_id}}).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
                }
            }
        }
    ),
    competence_type = sequelize.define('competence_type', {
        id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    });
Competence.belongsTo(competence_type,{foreignKey: 'competence_type_id'});
```

Notice the add function which is the one i am using to add new elements.

This is my `competence` variable:

[image]

However once i save none of my callback functions are being called not `onSuccess` nor `onError`

Can anyone help me out here i am going crazy!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize uses [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) for promises. So you should use [`.then`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#thenfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise) and [`.catch`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#catchfunction-handler---promise) methods, not `.success`(`.ok`) and `.error`. `.error` has another meaning in bluebird (see [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#error-rejectedhandler----promise)). So for example `.add` method can be written like:

```
add: function (onSuccess, onError) {
    var competence = this.dataValues;

    Competence.build(competence).save().then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
}
```